# updating file icon type to MySQL from it's adress

Tags: php, mysql

i'd like to repair my file type icons, 'cause i didn't set the icon during the upload and now i don't want to set it for each file, but do it with this in a second:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `upload_files` WHERE id > '0'";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
echo mysql_error();
while($pole = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $filename = $pole['file_adress'];
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.'));
    $file_ext = str_replace(".","",$file_ext);
    mysql_query("UPDATE  `d30268_acko`.`upload_files` SET  `icon` =  '/img/file_ico/$file_ext.png' WHERE  `upload_files`.`file_adress` = $file_ext;");
    echo $pole['icon']."<br>";
    }
    echo "Done";
```

`file adress` is for example `rokoko.odt` and from this i want just `odt`, this is what i have now, but i need update about 100 rows to set file type icon

can anyone help me please? it just set `icon` same type for all of the files, thanks.

Comment: what in the above code you want help with? It's not clear.

Comment: i have problem in `mysql_query` - it updates the whole table, but with the same type, so it looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/6w9n3jcd9/
this means, that i don't want the odt.png icon for pdf file.. i want pdf.png for pdf file :D

Comment: does replacing `= $file_ext;` with `= '$file_ext'` help?

Comment: nope, it's something different - i want pick the file extension from `file_adress` column and insert it into `icon` column in my MySQL table, but this `mysql_query` inserts same file extension for every file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update your query to

```
UPDATE  `d30268_acko`.`upload_files` SET  `icon` =  '/img/file_ico/$file_ext.png' WHERE  `upload_files`.`file_adress` LIKE '%.{$file_ext}'
```